Sci-fi novel set on a strange planet where the head of a corporation is killed and rebuilt by a secretive faction
I remember reading a novel (may have been multiple novels printed in one book) back in the 90s or early 2000s.
It took place on a strange planet with lots of weird stuff going on. It is ignored or quarantined by humans on Earth but an entire nearly lawless society lives there. The main character was the head of a corporation. Some wild corporate war takes place and eventually the man is killed and rebuilt by a secretive faction that uses nano machines and travels back in time to Earth.
Cannot remember the name or find it anywhere.

What weird stuff was going on? Any details you can remember might help jog our memories. After all, 1990 is a long time ago.
